# c++ using constructor together with _exit() function

Tags: c++, destructor, exit

I have a question about the `_exit()` function regarding destructors.

I found that calling `_exit()` does not call destructors.

In this example of "main.cpp", the destructor of `someThing` is nicely called.

main.cpp

```
//doesnt realy matter how the SomeThing class looks like, except to mention that the destructor is used.
std::unique_ptr<SomeThing> something = std::unique_ptr<SomeThing>(nullptr);

int main()
{
    something.start();
    return 0;
}
```

On "main2.cpp", the destructor of `sometThing` is not called.

main2.cpp

```
std::unique_ptr<SomeThing> something = std::unique_ptr<SomeThing>(nullptr);

int main()
{
    something.start();
    _exit(0);
}
```

On "main3.cpp", the destructor of `someThing` is also not called.

main3.cpp

```
std::unique_ptr<SomeThing> something = std::unique_ptr<SomeThing>(nullptr);

void exit()
{
    _exit(0);
}

int main()
{
    std::atexit(exit);
    something.start();
    return 0;
}
```

main4.cpp

```
std::unique_ptr<SomeThing> something = std::unique_ptr<SomeThing>(nullptr);

int main()
{
    something.start();
    something.~unique_ptr(); //is this ok to call this?
    _exit(0);
}
```

I am bound (to a custom framework) that uses the `_exit()` function

So my questions are:

1. Why is the destructor on "main3.cpp" not called this way?
2. What is the porpose using `_exit()` above `return 0;`?
3. How can I use `_exit()` and still call the destructor of `someThing`?
4. Is it considered bad practice to use the example in main4.cpp?

Comment: From the man page _"...terminates the calling process "immediately"..."_ https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/exit.2.html As the process is killed, no destructors will be run. Kernel resources will be clean up (eg file handles will be closed) but no clean up will happen in the application code.

Comment: To further quote the manpage: "The function _exit() is like exit(3), but does not call any functions registered with atexit(3) or on_exit(3)."

Comment: The answer to point 3 is "you can't".

Comment: I understand, but the _exit() function is called from the atexit registered function (in main3.cpp) and still the destructor of "someThing" is not called

Comment: Case (3) looks like it should clean up but the exact order of static destruction and exit function(s) has changed in different Standard versions.  What version of C++ are you compiling with ?

Comment: I have added a case 4, this works, but is this correct to do this?

I am compiling with C++14

Comment: Why do you even use exit()? Honestly, I don't see any good reason to use that syscall. And from my perspective when you have to use it, then you probably have a deeper issue, some design problem.

Comment: In 3) your registered function happens to be called before the destruction of the static object, thus terminating immediately. Re version 4: explicit destruction is rarely a good idea; just say `something.reset();` (or add a resetting function to whatever your actual class is) and let the machine Do The Right Thing. (Of course, this will not help at all when `_exit` is out of your control.)

Comment: @freakish me neither, but I am bound to a framework that forces it, it woudnt been my choice aswell.

Comment: Why do you want to run the destructors? If you depend on useful work being done in the destructors of global objects, you should revisit your decision.

Comment: in te destructor is some cleaning done, deleting pointers and closing connections

Comment: I think I will make a "clean" function or something instead of the destructor and then call this "clean" function before _exit.

Comment: What happens if your program crashes? The connections stay open? If you know where to call `clean()` and what to do inside of it, you don't need global objects in the first place. Just put everything that needs to be cleaned in the same scope you want to put `clean` in, and let the desctructors do the job.

Comment: Yeah, the only reason i have that object global is because a signal handler that catches ctrl c, so it sets a Boolean on false so the main loop exits, after that, the clean functions are used, if the object isn't global, the signal handler cannot reach it to exit the main loop